# Django contact form sending email

Tags: python, django, email, contact-form

I created a contact form to send me an email when the user fills it out. Everything appears to be working, but I'm not getting an email.

Here's my console output:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Michael Plemmons
From: mplemmons1982@gmail.com
To: californiamikegreen@yahoo.com
Date: Thu, 02 Nov 2017 22:40:50 -0000
Message-ID: <20171102224050.12741.24539@ubuntu>

hello this is a test
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[02/Nov/2017 22:40:50] "POST /contact/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[02/Nov/2017 22:40:50] "GET /success/ HTTP/1.1" 200 36
```

This is views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import *
from .forms import contact_form
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = contact_form()
    else:
        form = contact_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = form.cleaned_data['contact_name']
            contact_email = form.cleaned_data['contact_email']
            contact_message = form.cleaned_data['contact_message']
            try:
                send_mail(contact_name, contact_message, contact_email, ['californiamikegreen@yahoo.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, "contact.html", {'form': form})


def success(request):
    return HttpResponse('Success! Thank you for your message.')
```

This is urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'contact/$',views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^success/$', views.success, name='success'),
]
```

this is forms.py

```
from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class contact_form(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(label='Contact Name', max_length=255)
    contact_email = forms.CharField(label='Contact Email',max_length=255)
    contact_message = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea
    )
```

and contact.html

```
{% block title %}Contact - {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Contact</h1>
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

And this included in settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Is there anything I am missing to get this to actually go to my email?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The [console backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#console-backend), as the name suggests, prints out the email to the console and doesn't do anything else.

You need to use a different email backend, for example the [smtp backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#smtp-backend) is the default:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

You'll then have to configure your settings like `EMAIL_HOST` with your email provider's settings. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#smtp-backend) for more info.

If you don't want to use the SMTP backend, another common choice is to use a transactional mail provider like Mailgun or SendGrid. Some of these services have free usage tiers which should be sufficient for a low-volume contact form. The [django-anymail](https://github.com/anymail/django-anymail) app supports several transactional mail providers.

Comment: Oh wow, more complicated than anticipated. Well I replaced console with smtp, but I'm confused about the rest. I read up on it and from my understanding, if I don't supply any arguments, it uses default values which should be sufficient. Where do I set all other values if I need to? I'm not picky and don't have any specific requirements, I just want it to go to my yahoo email. When I run it as is, it says connection refused. I saw I need to call mail.get_connection() as connection. I don't see where I need to call this. In views.py before I send the form information?

Comment: If you don't set any of the `EMAIL_` settings, then Django will try to use `localhost`. If you don't have a mail server running, then you'll get errors. If you want to use Yahoo, then you need to to set `EMAIL_HOST_USER`, `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD`, and other settings e.g. `EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yahoo.com'` (I don't know whether that's the correct domain). You may find that it doesn't work, even with the correct SMTP settings (I see lots of questions on Stack Overflow about people having problems with Gmail). For that reason, it might be easier to use a transactional mail provider as I suggested.

Comment: You don't have to call `mail.get_connection() as connection` anywhere. If your email settings are correctly configured, then your current `send_mail()` command should work just fine.

Comment: You may also find that using the user's email address as the `from_email` may cause problems (mail servers don't like an email with "from john.doe@gmail.com" coming from a non-Google server). The solution to this is to use your own email address as the `from_email`, and use their email as `reply_to` (you need to use [`EmailMessage`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects) instead of `send_mail` for this).

Comment: ah wow ok thank you very much. Your explanation helped me a lot.